I try build hasmany relation between card and product table . But I can not access products attributes . It shows null
//my controller
public function show_card(){
    if(Auth::id())
    {
        $id=Auth::user()->id;
        $cards=Card::with('product_card')->where('user_id','=',$id)->get();
        return view('home.show_cart',compact('cards'));
    }
    else{
        return redirect('login');
    }
}

//product model
public function product_card()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Card::class,'product_id','id');
}


//card model

public function product_card() 
{ 
return $this->belongsTo(Product::class); 
}

//I want to access product table data using product_id foreign key in card table.`

In your Product model, you should define the relationship as a hasMany because one product can be associated with many cards:
public function cards()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Card::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}

In your Card model, you should define the relationship as a belongsTo because each card belongs to one product:
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}

With these corrections, you should be able to access product attributes from the cards. Here's how you would do it in your controller:
public function show_card()
{
    if(Auth::id())
    {
        $id = Auth::user()->id;
        $cards = Card::with('product')->where('user_id', $id)->get();
        return view('home.show_cart', compact('cards'));
    }
    else {
        return redirect('login');
    }
}

Now, when you access $card->product->attribute, you should get the attributes of the associated product. Make sure your database schema is correctly set up with the foreign key constraints.
